# Zybooks: 18.7 PROJECT A Game of Dice

Tags: python, project

I've gotten steps 1-7 done but im stuck on step 8 and dont know what to do or fix with the response of the error. Here's what I have, please help:

```
import random


def first_roll():
    d1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    d2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    sum_of_die = d1 + d2
    if sum_of_die == 7 or sum_of_die == 11:
        print("Rolled dice: ({},{}).".format(d1, d2), sum_of_die, "wins")
        point = 1
    elif sum_of_die == 2 or sum_of_die == 3 or sum_of_die == 12:
        print("Rolled dice: ({},{}).".format(d1, d2), sum_of_die, "loses")
        point = -1
    else:
        point = sum_of_die
        print("Point = ", point)
    return point


def next_rolls(point):
    end = 1
    result = 0

    while end == 1:
        d1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        d2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        sum_of_die = d1 + d2
        if sum_of_die == 7:
            print("Rolled dice: ({},{}).".format(d1, d2), sum_of_die, "loses")
            result = -1
            end = 0
        elif sum_of_die == point:
            print("Rolled dice: ({},{}).".format(d1, d2), sum_of_die, "wins")
            result = 1
            end = 0
        else:
            print("Rolled dice: ({},{}).".format(d1, d2), ".", "Roll again.")
            continue
    return result

def play_one_round(credits):
    outcome = first_roll()
    if outcome <= 1:
        credits = credits + outcome
    else:
        outcome2 = next_rolls(outcome)
        print(outcome2)
        credits = credits + outcome2
    return credits


def play_multiple_rounds(rounds, credits):
    for x in range(0,rounds):
        while play_one_round(credits) >= 1:
            print("Round", rounds,":", "Credits", credits)
    return credits


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_roll()
```

Im just lost, i dont know what to fix in the multiple plays definition to get it to work.

### The error says "Program generated too much output. Output restricted to 50000 characters. Check program for any unterminated loops generating output." and then says my code outputs:
"Point =  4
Rolled dice: (1,5). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (3,4). 7 loses

### Round 50 : Credits 20
Point =  9
Rolled dice: (3,2). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (6,2). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (3,4). 7 loses

### Round 50 : Credits 20
Rolled dice: (1,2). 3 loses
Round 50 : Credits 20
Point =  9
Rolled dice: (1,1). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (1,6). 7 loses

### Round 50 : Credits 20
Point =  8
Rolled dice: (1,5). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (6,6). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (4,3). 7 loses

Round 50 : Credits 20
Rolled dice: (1,2). 3 loses
Round 50 : Credits 20
Point =  6
Rolled dice: (3,6). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (2,5). 7 loses
-1..." without explaination

Answer (score 0):

,

soo calling multiple times the random fonction it may cause an error, your code seem incomplete so try to publish the rest with the callings and the error this should help to understand in which line its posing problem.

Good Luck,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code replacing the initial function call in your "main" loop from "first_roll()" to "play_multiple_rounds(4, 4)" to test out your code.  Indeed, the program gets stuck in an endless loop.  The culprit is the line of code is your "while" test.

```
while play_one_round(credits) >= 1:
```

When this code executes, the result of the function call is used for the test; however, the value of "credits" is not being replaced with this value as I am guessing is what is desired.  So, this while loop will never be exited in that fashion.

With that in mind, I did a small bit of refactoring as follows.

```
def play_multiple_rounds(rounds, credits):
    for x in range(0,rounds):
        while credits >= 1:
            credits = play_one_round(credits)
            print("Round", x,":", "Credits", credits)
    return credits

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_multiple_rounds(4,4)
```

The "while" test is simplified to check if the value of "credits" is going to zero.  Then, the credits variable is updated with a call to the "play_one_round(credits)" function.  This then properly increments or decrements the credits variable which can allow for the game to end if the player runs out of credits (money).

Following was a test of this refactored code in the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Craps$ python3 Craps.py 
Rolled dice: (6,6). 12 loses
Round 0 : Credits 3
Point =  6
Rolled dice: (5,2). 7 loses
-1
Round 0 : Credits 2
Point =  8
Rolled dice: (5,4). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (1,2). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (4,4). 8 wins
1
Round 0 : Credits 3
Rolled dice: (2,1). 3 loses
Round 0 : Credits 2
Point =  5
Rolled dice: (4,4). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (1,5). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (1,3). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (6,3). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (3,1). . Roll again.
Rolled dice: (3,4). 7 loses
-1
Round 0 : Credits 1
Rolled dice: (6,5). 11 wins
Round 0 : Credits 2
Point =  6
Rolled dice: (3,4). 7 loses
-1
Round 0 : Credits 1
Point =  5
Rolled dice: (5,2). 7 loses
-1
Round 0 : Credits 0
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.